# Load balancing vs hardware clustering

Tags: load-balancer

Which one is the most common high availability techniques? It seems that I can't distinguis the different between the two concept.

Comment: Asking which is most common is difficult to answer.  Do you really need us to explain which is most common, or is it enough to cover the difference between clustering and load balancing?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Load balancing spreads incoming requests across a pool of servers, each of which is a mostly independent system. Clustering creates one big server out of a pool of hardware boxes, which are tightly linked. Load balancing is generally easier to manage and maintain, so it is becoming the preferred solution for many applications.

Sometimes the servers are load balanced, but the application is clustered - this is a built-in feature of most large-scale database software, to ensure that separate copies of the database can't get out of sync.

Web server systems are often built with one load balancing server (to distribute incoming requests), a pool of web servers (to serve the requests), and a pool of database servers running a clustered database (so everyone sees the same data).